# Submitting with jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to learn how these websites are validating data with PHP. For instance you go to facebooks page and view the source code there is no form action supplied. Ok I understand they are using Javascript in some manner to post data towards PHP but can I do something similar with jquery? Are the submit() and Post() functions that I should learn in depth to achieve the results. Could some one shed some light how these websites are doing all this or is it just Ajax? Thanks help is much appreciated and if there is some tutorial you would recommend please do tell!

Comment: read up on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 1):

To answer your title issue, an easy way to post forms with ajax is the form plugin:

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

It's veery easy to use. Just do:

```
   $(document).ready(function() { 
       $('form').ajaxForm(function() { 
          alert("Your form has been submitted!!"); //Put your logic here
       }); 
   });
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what http requests are being made on submits or javascript calls etc - install some packet sniffing software.  Like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

> Fiddler is a Web Debugging Proxy which
>   logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your
>   computer and the Internet. Fiddler
>   allows you to inspect all HTTP(S)
>   traffic, set breakpoints, and "fiddle"
>   with incoming or outgoing data

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's AJAX.

Yes, you should look up [.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).